# Google anlytics is not working integrated in android app ,real time data is not showing

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

I have two account of google analytics , but one account giving all data fine ,but another is not giving data ,not even real time data , I am integrate code as per [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

please anyone have an idea about it ,thanks in advance ?

Comment: u need to post your code and analytic.xml

Comment: I have not added any analytic.xml in my code

Comment: doing same code as this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced

Comment: My code is working fine ..but My one account from india and another have settings time as south africa .... so my south africa account is not working , is anything because of GMT time set ?

Comment: i thing it also possible becuse during crating id it will ask so it also possible.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things to take note of:

- There might be a dispatching delay from the time you call the hits to the time when hits are sent. Can you make sure dispatch time is same on both the trackers/properties
- Check if there are differences in settings for the two accounts? Is one of the account a App property instead of web property?
- Realtime does not take into account your timezone afaik so it should not affect the reports.